# Unresponsive tabs in Chrome and Safari after upgrading to GWT 2.8

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, safari, gwt-2.8

Recently I've attempted to upgrade to GWT 2.8 but ran into an issue where a small number of users report browser tabs hanging (eventually putting up kill/wait popups) in Chrome 55.0.2883.95 and Safari 10.0.2. Seems to affect Mac users primarily. Going back to GWT 2.7 made the issue go away. I haven't been able to reproduce the issue myself, so it doesn't seem to be a general problem. Has anybody experienced anything similar after upgrading?